# Question about the types `std::basic_string<char>::size_type` and `size_t` in the solution shown below

Tags: c++, types

What is the difference between `std::basic_string<char>::size_type` and `size_t`?

Some extra context: I have in mind something like the function in the code example appearing in the SO question linked below. There, an STL array is constructed for the purposes of parsing a string and saving information to said array. In the code example, default array values of `std::string::npos` are used, and if the npos values are never replaced during the life of the function, a -1 must be returned from the function. The underlying spirit of this question is to get at best practices for type usage in a context such as this.

I posted a separate question that contains a code example containing the above constructs: [Question about npos and -1 for the output of a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73604472/question-about-npos-and-1-for-the-output-of-a-c-function)

Comment: `static_cast<std::size_t>(26)` may be `26U`, or just `26`.

Comment: *Is it correct to say that std::string::npos is the largest value?* - no. It's [`max_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size).

Comment: This "question" seems more suited to codereview as it's asking about coding style for working code . Also it is 4 questions in 1 whereas SO questions should be one question per question .

Comment: SO is a question and answer site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural. It's not a *here's my numbered list of questions* site. One question per post is an integral part of the site design. You may want to go back and review the [help] pages to better understand how the site works before your next post.

Comment: @M.M I apologize if I wasn't more clear. I'm just asking for the definitions of C++ types. I'm just asking: What is the difference between std::basic_string<char>::size_type, std::string::npos, and size_t when constructing and initializing a STL array for the purposes of parsing a string and saving information to said array... when the default values must be the max value for a char which later needs to be easily convertible to -1? Asking this way is a bit terse in my mind... but if you have time to answer this version it would definitely be sufficient :)

Comment: @KenWhite Sure, no problem. I changed it. Was just trying to make the question easily digestible the first time :) I guess I'll be caught between a rock and a hard place if people now ask for more context. lol

Comment: @273K Yup, 26U would have been fine in the context oriented first draft that apparently wasn't appropriate for SO. I was trying to avoid 26 though to avoid anything that required an implicit conversion because I wanted to be explicit about types in a definite context to ask something about different types. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @M.M I think this is a perfectly good answer. Maybe a small example of the "may or may not [be the same]" for typedefs std::string::size_type and size_t, and I think it will be useful for people with doubts about this (and answer my question fully). I'll accept it right away. Thank :)

Comment: Voted to reopen as the question no longer contains four sub-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::string` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>` (so you do not need to keep unpacking this).

`std::string::size_type` is a typedef for an unsigned type large enough to hold the length of any string. Usually this is a typedef for `size_t` although that is not a guarantee,  so very robust code shouldn't rely on it.

`std::string::npos` is the value `-1` converted to `std::string::size_type` . So it is the largest possible value that can be held by `std::string::size_type` .

Note that converting from `std::string::size_type` to `int` may be lossy since `int` is narrower than `size_t` generally, so you could not rely on `(int)npos` being `-1`.

Comment: This all makes sense. Thanks! Looks like it would be more robust then to do something like `auto max_std_string_size_type = std::string::npos` and use the `max_std_string_size_type` constant throughout. Then "manually" return -1 if a test for max_std_string_size_type returns true.

Comment: Looks like you have a well established reputation so I thought maybe you could guide me here. I just saw that after you answered the question, the question was closed with offers to delete the question or edit it. Any thoughts? I'm hesitant to delete it after your nice answer. But I'm also not sure how you'd want me to edit it so that your answer is still well connected to the question. If I don't hear back I'll probably just leave it as is I suppose.

Comment: `std::string::size_type` is defined as `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char>>::size_type`, which *is* guaranteed to be the same as `std::size_t`. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Of course, `size_type` may be something else for other instantiations of `std::basic_string`.

Comment: @bcsb1001 OK go ahead an edit answer to include

Comment: @tarstevs your suggestion in comment is worse than just using `std::string::npos`

Comment: @M.M You might be right, but why is it worse? I tested it and it works. Do you mean it is stylistically clanky? What I'm saying worked is: --->
std::string::size_type max_std_string_size_type = std::string::npos;
... and later on: ---->
//** static casting to int64_t to match return type of function which
is int64_t to allow for negative values (we have to be able to return -1 when there are no unique chars). **//
 int64_t result = static_cast<int64_t>(*std::min_element(pos.begin(), pos.end()));
 return result == static_cast<int64_t>(max_std_string_size_type) ? -1 : result;

Comment: @tarstevs `npos` is already a `std::string::size_type`. This is like writing `int ten = 10;` and then using `ten` everywhere instead of `10`.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer. casting to signed into is not reliable ; you should instead return `result` if the result you want was found, and `-1` if it wasn't.  And not involve some kind of trip through `npos`

Comment: @M.M Yup yup. So stylistically clanky. If it's cleaner (and I think it probably is) it could be npos everywhere and then the last line [from the comment I just wrote above] turns into: `return result == static_cast<int64_t>(std::string::npos) ? -1 : result;`. Either way the lossy issue is avoided.

Comment: @M.M Regarding not using npos: The whole algorithm rests upon the use of `*std::min_element(pos.begin(), pos.end())` from the algorithms library, which wouldn't work without npos. Other "index of first unique char" algorithms could work without npos (such as using std::list with std::unordered_map instead of two arrays). It's too bad the original example algorithm isn't there so people could know what we are talking about... but I'm assuming it's findable in the edits??

Comment: `static_cast<int64_t>(std::string::npos)` is not guaranteed to give `-1`

Comment: I can't comment on your code without a code sample, maybe you could post a new question with the code sample asking about how to correctly return -1 if not found

Comment: @M.M Sure. I thought I explained above that the workaround is testing for the npos value and "manually" providing -1... so there is no longer a risk of running into the "npos to int is lossy and not guaranteed to give -1" issue. Nonetheless, I posted the code (with a sort of made up question) so you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73604472/question-about-npos-and-1-for-the-output-of-a-c-function. It seems increasingly clear that having everything in one place as it was at the start was sensible if for no other reason than to respect everyone's time.